# using ng-click to update every cell in a table column

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I was trying to figure out how to have the data in one of the columns in a table I made convert from one number format to another when the user clicks on the top of the table cell. I've create a filter already, but i don't know how to call it so it effects all the cells in the table.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.name}} </td>
    <td>{{x.desc}}></td>
    <td>{{x.number}}</td> <--- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CONVERT
 </tr>
```

I'm not even sure where to start with this. I basically have a ng-click directive call "convert" which I've defined in the controller. I know that if I define a variable in the $scope (such as $scope.foo = "1") and then call the convert() function I can replace the value like this:

```
  $scope.convert = function(){
     $scope.foo = 2;
  }
```

And then my table updates with that value. But what if every table cell in that column has a different value, and I basically want to run that value through a filter I've made.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: where you want to add click handler ? and what is logic of function to convert the number?

Comment: The click handler would be in the table row header: The filter function i have would just convert it's format and then print the new format back to the table cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you already have a filter?
Then just give your filter an argument 'numberFormat':

```
angular.
  module('yourModule').
  filter('yourFilter', function() {
    return function(input, numberFormat) {
      // convert the input according to the numberFormat
      return filteredValue;
    };
  });
```

Then you can update the format in your convert() scope-method:

```
$scope.convert = function(){
     $scope.numberFormat = 'long';
  }
```

and pass it to your filter:

```
<td>{{x.number | yourFilter:numberFormat}}</td>
```

BTW:
Read about controllerAs - IMHO it is a better practice to store values at the controller rrather than directly on the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your function simply needs to update `number` property of the each object in the `data` array. You could do it like this:

```
$scope.convert = function() {
  $scope.data.forEach(function(item) {
    item.number = item.number + 2; // Convert number somehow
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume click handler on table header of column as below

```
<th ng-click="convert()">column of number</th>
```

in the controller write the function as below

```
$scope.convert = function() {
    $scope.data.forEach(function(obj) {
       obj.number += 1;
    })
    //$scope.$apply() use this is template is not refreshed
}
```